# Why is gfs undefined when passed to another function using gridfs-stream and mongoose in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

#### I'm trying to connect to the database and declare the gfs variable in one file and share it to another file where I want to fetch the file details

**mongo.connection.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let gfs; // Declare gfs variable outside the EstConnection function

const EstConnection = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI);
    const connect = mongoose.connection;
    connect.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
    connect.once("open", function () {
      console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
      gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connect.db, { bucketName: "uploads" });
      // Call any other functions that depend on gfs here
    });

    return gfs;

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};

module.exports = { EstConnection, gfs }; // Export the gfs variable
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const { gfs } = require("../connnection/mongo.connection");

exports.postRetriveAll = async (res, req) => {
  try {
    // await establishConnection();

    console.log("Retrieved gfs:", gfs);

    // Retrieve all file details from the "uploads" bucket
    gfs.find({}).toArray((err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Files:", files);
      }
    });
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

**Output**

```
Mongoose connection successful.
Retrieved gfs: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
```

i have called establishConnection() function in app.js file initially and also called it once again in user.controller.js but it didn't worked i also used the promise method but it didn't work

I'm trying to pass the gfs variable which i have declared in one file to another file to retrieve the file data from database, the gfs variable should be passed normally without undefined, the program is working fine if i write like all the operations at single file inside one block but it's now helpful for me.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let gfs; // Declare gfs variable outside the EstConnection function

const EstConnection = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI);
    const connect = mongoose.connection;
    connect.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
    connect.once("open", function () {
      console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
      gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connect.db, { bucketName: "uploads" });

      console.log("Retrieved gfs:", gfs);

    // Retrieve all file details from the "uploads" bucket
      gfs.find({}).toArray((err, files) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error:", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Files:", files);
        }
      });
    });

   // return gfs;

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
};

module.exports = { EstConnection, gfs }; // Export the gfs variable
```

In the above program i'm able to console the result but cannot store the result in any variable.